# Display the alert box when change the @html.DropDownList value

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

```
  @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Status, new List<SelectListItem> 
       { new SelectListItem{Text="Active", Value="1",Selected =true},
         new SelectListItem{Text="Deactive", Value="0"}})
```

If i change the value Active to De active display the one alert box. How to display the alert box.

Comment: Off-Topic: If you want the opposite of active, use "Inactive" or "Passive", maybe even "Idle" depending on the context. But as far as I can recall Deactive is not a valid term.

Comment: Take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17950703/using-selected-value-in-html-dropdownlistfor

Answer (score 0):

You could use the change() handler in Jquery to listen for the event.

```
$( "#targetId").change(function() {
     alert( "Something changed handle it here" );
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: I am new for asp.net mvc. please tell how to call jquery function from dropdowenlistfor

Comment: Add this javascript code to your .cshtml file in a `<script>` block.

Comment: Read through this: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification Very interesting info :)

Comment: new {@id="targetId"} and call the script function this way is right

Comment: Exactly, `#targetId`, refers to the id of the `<select>`, you can define this as an optional paramater in the definition of it using `{@id="targetId"}`

Answer (score 0):

```
  Razor:-


 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Status, new List<SelectListItem> 
               { new SelectListItem{Text="Active", Value="1",Selected =true},
                 new SelectListItem{Text="Deactive", Value="0"}})
```

Jquery(Change event is called when you change the dropdownlist value whose id is attached in below query) :-

```
 <script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('select#status').change(function() {
            alert("value changed. New value is " + $(this).val());
    });
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: please wait @neel i am new for mvc

Comment: cshtml page:@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Status, new List<SelectListItem> 
           { new SelectListItem{Text="Active", Value="1",Selected =true},
             new SelectListItem{Text="Deactive", Value="0"},new {@id="ddlTMManagers"}}) and put scripting code: $(function() {
    $('select#ddlDMManagers').change(function() {
        alert("value changed. New value is " + $(this).val());
});

Comment: i got this error: The best overloaded Add method 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>.Add(System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem)' for the collection initializer has some invalid arguments

Comment: that was happening coz of syntax error..try my updated ans @satheeshkumarMCA

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your master layout or in view in which Dropdown is:

### First Way:

Jquery CODE:

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){

     $('select#status').change(function() {
            alert($(this).val());
    });
});

</script>
```

### Second Way:

Or you can add your own id like this:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Status, new List<SelectListItem> 
               { new SelectListItem{Text="Active", Value="1",Selected =true},
                 new SelectListItem{Text="Deactive", Value="0"}
               },
                 null,
                 new {@id="DDLStatus"})
```

and script:

```
  <script>

        $(document).ready(function(){

         $('select#DDLStatus').change(function() {
                alert($(this).val());
        });
    });

    </script>
```

**Note:** make sure that jquery script file is included in your master layout mostly it is in **View --> Shared --> _Layout.cshtml**

Comment: {@id="DDLStatus"})}) in this extra you put ")" this symbol

Comment: i got this kind of erroe.The best overloaded Add method 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>.Add(System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem)' for the collection initializer has some invalid arguments

Comment: i missed closing `}` of SelectListItem List now fixed

Comment: in my cshtml page: @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Status, new List<SelectListItem> 
           { new SelectListItem{Text="Active", Value="1",Selected =true},
             new SelectListItem{Text="Deactive", Value="0"},new {@id="DDLStatus"}})

Comment: its wrong it should be: ``@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Status, new List<SelectListItem> 
               { new SelectListItem{Text="Active", Value="1",Selected =true},
                 new SelectListItem{Text="Deactive", Value="0"}
               },
                 null,
                 new {@id="DDLStatus"})``

Comment: value=1 for active i select the active and click the submit button status value is set false

Comment: make sure jquery included and check console to see if any syntax or runtime error of js

Comment: sorry i include which jquery

Comment: (vaue=1 and value=0) two thinks pass the false value only. i changed (value=true and value=false) it's corrected pass the true and false. but i am using(value=true and value=false) drop down-list value default display deactive

Comment: what you trying to do?

Comment: Change the status true to false in my database false mean employee status is detective

Comment: so whay you are adding jquery event?

Comment: i change dropdoewn list value active to deactivate show the one alert box